# How to the make navbar menu clean in mobile devices with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here is my *navbar* code:

```
<nav id="nav_wrapper" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="BKoodakBold leftlinks"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> &nbsp; ورورد به اکانت کاربری</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="50" height="30"></a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#">درباره ما &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#" >میراث گویانت &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#">صفحه اصلی &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is the output of my menu in the normal size:

[image: image1]

It looks nice but when it comes to mobile devices it changes to this:

[image: image2]

As you can see it looks messy and un clean! So I want to make this clean actually. I mean I want to move the navbar-brand to the bottom of navbar-collapse menu & adjust all the menu links to be float to the left and also they should one after another. Just like this example:

[image: image3]

So my question is how can I do this thing within css or jquery ?

And this is my custom css style for the navbar in small devices:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#nav_wrapper{
    opacity:1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the placement of your second ul with the last one. I mean, move the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">..</ul>` before "`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">...</ul>`".